# Google App Script IF statement for Sending Emails

Tags: javascript, email, if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Just want to ask some help regarding with my coding in Google App Script.

Objective: Am trying to send emails once I satisfy the 3 condition (the 2 condition is in the same column). And once the script already sent an email to that specific control number the script shouldn't send again to that transaction. However it still sending emails even if the script already sent to that transaction. I can't find where the problem is or if am not satisfying the condition I set.

Column SubmissionStatus have "Final, Cancelled, Draft"
Column processBy have ("ADMIN" only)

```
  if (submissionStatus !== "Draft" && processBy !== "") { // Prevents sending duplicates  
  var subject = "Cash_Advance ";
  MailApp.sendEmail(currentEmail, subjectline, messageBody);
  sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 38).setValue(EMAIL_SENT +" "+ Date()); // column AL
  // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  } //close if statement

  if (submissionStatus !== "Cancelled" && processBy !== "") { // Prevents sending duplicates  
  var subject = "Cash_Advance ";
  MailApp.sendEmail(currentEmail, subjectline, messageBody);
  sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 38).setValue(EMAIL_SENT +" "+ Date()); // column AL
  // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  } //close if statement
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. When asking for debugging we encourage users to post a [mcve] . The question lacks of enough details to let others to reproduce the problem, please add some sample data specific, in this case to reproduce the if-statement that isn't working and remove from the code in the question the code lines that are not required to to make the if-statement to work.

Comment: Please show how you are getting the `submissionStatus` and `processBy`or confirm that they contain the correct information using `console.log()`. Also, your variable `subject` is never used, instead you are passing `subjectline` as the argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply merge those two if statement into one, maybe that's why it is sending email more than once.

By using `submissionStatus === "Final"`

In context of your latest edit:-

> Column SubmissionStatus have "Final, Cancelled, Draft" Column
> processBy have ("ADMIN" only)

**Modification:**

```
if (submissionStatus === "Final" && processBy !== "") // Prevents sending duplicates  
{ 
          var subject = "Cash_Advance ";
          MailApp.sendEmail(currentEmail, subjectline, messageBody);
          sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 38).setValue(EMAIL_SENT +" "+ Date()); // column AL
          // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
          SpreadsheetApp.flush();
 } //close if statement
```